# Eclipse CDT list all files from a project library

Tags: eclipse, makefile, eclipse-cdt

As a requirement for a project I must list all files that I have used and any files that they call, however; my project has gotten a bit large and the library I use has a long class inheritance. Is their a way in eclipse that allows me to see a list of all of the files required to build a project?